# Cutting through Shed style roof

Tags: roof, construction

I'd like to install a new window to increase ventilation & install a new window a/c in this room as the long window in the picture doesnt open. The only way I'd get an ideal window placement is if I cut through the shed style roof. I have 2 options for locations but both require cutting either end of the shed roof. 
The 1st pic would allow me to install a window of about 34"w. The 2nd  allows for a bigger window but am concerned removing the roof support.

How feasible is this project? Has this been done before? What do I need to be mindful of? What tools are best to use?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you even need that "shed" roof?

Comment: The question is too broad. Michael Karas did a good job of summarizing concerns, but [we're not a discussion forum](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour). You'd need to ask something more specific. Your project requires some fundamental carpentry knowledge, but is fairly straight-forward otherwise. More complicated is the framing of the actual window opening.

Answer (score 2):

From a distance view the project in the first photo appears feasible. There are many factors at play here including:

1. Whether you even need the shed roof at all and could simply fully remove it.
2. What may be inside the wall area already including wiring or plumbing vent.
3. Locations of existing studs in the wall and how framing has to change to accommodate the window.
4. Restoration of the house siding in area where roof is removed.
5. How to properly flash the window so that rain does not get into the wall.
6. Opening the shed roof to re-frame one end may result in need to re-shingle it.

Due to the nature of the questions you asked, including the question of what tools would be required, I would suggest that you at least get a couple of contractors to give you some bids on what they think it would take to complete this project. Being on site to see first hand they can give you a lot better idea of what is needed overall than we can from several photos. Even if you decide to do the work yourself the consultations will put you way forward in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need a portion of the roof to cover the portion of the storage closet that juts out ~2 ft from the house.  The crux of my post was about cutting into the shed style roof to fit a window & I appreciate your considerations. Is a reciprocating saw & or circular saw adequate to cut through that roof?

Comment: Both. You have multiple types and sizes of material to cut, so both are appropriate.